# Generar un teletransporte aleatorio con un portal

Tags: unity

Cómo Puedo hacer que mi personaje al tocar un objeto (un portal) se transporte a una posición random?

Y un segundo caso, cuando intento usar Random.Range() el Range se coloca en rojo y me dice "Cannot resolver symbol 'Range' porque pasa? No entiendo, intenté varias cosas y pasa igual

En un script que hice para aparecer una moneda en posiciones random me funcionaba bien el Random.Range, pero en el script de mi personaje no deja usarlo

Comment: Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Pulsa en [edit] para mostrar un [repro] del problema en cuestión. Y por las dudas: el código siempre _como texto, con formato_.

Answer (score 0):

respecto a la duda del *Random.Range*, es posible que el compilador esté confundiendo el Random que incorpora la librería *System* con el de la librería *UnityEngine*.

Para solucionar este problema, sólo tendrías que marcarle que librería necesitas, de la siguiente manera:

```
UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 10);
```

Respecto al desarrollo del portal, deberás de darnos más detalles ¿Se trata de un terreno regular?, ¿El terreno se va a encontrar en la misma escena?, ¿Va a haber obstáculos dónde el jugador no debería aparecer?

Espero haberte ayudado :)

Comment: Gracias, no entiendo aún el problema del Random.Range() pues en otro código me funcionaba totalmente bien sin necesidad de la librería, solo las que vienen por defecto, en caso del portal ya lo pude solucionar, era un juego 2d que el personaje necesitaba transportarse en algún lugar aleatorio de la cámara al tocar el portal. Hice básicamente lo mismo que en un código diferente y que a la vez era similar al código de un amigo. Que era hacer un float dentro del if del oncollisionenter2d, le definí los parámetros y todo bien